# How to shorten the time to build pyqt5 environment on travis?

Tags: installation, travis-ci, pyqt5

I have an PyQt5 project on github, and the following is my environment settings:

```
dist: trusty
sudo: required
language: python

python:
- 3.4
- 3.5

before_install:
  #SIP
  - cd ..
  - curl -L -O "https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/sip/sip-4.19.3/sip-4.19.3.tar.gz"
  - tar -xvf sip-4.19.3.tar.gz
  - cd sip-4.19.3
  - python configure.py
  - sudo make install
  #Qt5
  - sudo add-apt-repository -y "ppa:beineri/opt-qt59-trusty"
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install qt59-meta-full qt59charts-no-lgpl
  - QTDIR="/opt/qt59"
  - PATH="$QTDIR/bin:$PATH"
  - source /opt/qt59/bin/qt59-env.sh
  - qmake -v
  #PyQt5
  - cd ..
  - curl -L -O "https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.9/PyQt5_gpl-5.9.tar.gz"
  - tar -xvf PyQt5_gpl-5.9.tar.gz
  - cd PyQt5_gpl-5.9
  - python configure.py --confirm-license
  - sudo make install
  #QScintilla
  - cd ..
  - curl -L -O "https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/QScintilla2/QScintilla-2.10.1/QScintilla_gpl-2.10.1.tar.gz"
  - tar -xvf QScintilla_gpl-2.10.1.tar.gz
  - cd QScintilla_gpl-2.10.1
  - cd Qt4Qt5
  - qmake qscintilla.pro
  - sudo make install
  - cd ../designer-Qt4Qt5
  - qmake designer.pro
  - sudo make install
  - cd ../Python
  - python configure.py --pyqt=PyQt5
  - sudo make install
  #PyQtChart
  - cd ../..
  - curl -L -O "https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQtChart/PyQtChart-5.9/PyQtChart_gpl-5.9.tar.gz"
  - tar -xvf PyQtChart_gpl-5.9.tar.gz
  - cd PyQtChart_gpl-5.9
  - python configure.py
  - sudo make install
  - cd $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR

install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - pip install pyinstaller

script:
 - make

before_cache:
  - rm -rf $HOME/.cache/pip/log
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.cache/pip
```

My project requires SIP, PyQt 5.7 or higher (for PyQtChart), QScintilla and some python modules.

One can imagine that it has been more than 50 minutes.

Is there any way to make these steps faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a workaround than a proper fix, but I've been using miniconda to successfully install pyqt for me. This isn't super fast but is a lot faster than what you're currently doing.

The following lines will get you into a python virtual environment with pyqt installed:

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh;
bash ./miniconda.sh -b -p ${HOME}/miniconda;
export PATH=${HOME}/miniconda/bin:$PATH;
conda install --yes python="2.7" pyqt;
```

Another solution could be using the unofficial PyPI exposed and maintained here: https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5

By running `pip install python-qt5`. Keep in mind this is not official and may break/disfunction. Use at your own risk.

Additionally, keep in mind that with python 3.5 and up, you can install pyqt5 using pip by simply running

```
pip3 install pyqt5
```

Last but not least, Travis' maintainers may be willing to add pyqt builds as part of their own environments, either pre-installed or available as precompiled binaries for installation using pip.

I'll +1 any such request.